# Is there a theorem or an axiom that an empty set is the smallest set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

An empty set has zero elements. How to show that this set has the lowest power?

---

In case of distances we have an axiom that distance is non-negative. But in ZFC I don't see a similar axiom. And it is unclear, how to derive it from ZFC.

Comment: Because it is a subset of every set.

Comment: Or that it has no proper subsets

Comment: Right now, in this post "smallest" and "smaller" and "lowest" are undefined terms for sets. So the first task is to write a rigorous definition of what is meant by those terms. Once the rigorous definition is present, I suspect it will be easy for you (the OP) to answer your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the order relation you're talking about.

For $\subseteq$, the emptyset is defined by the property $\forall x\, x\not\in\emptyset$.  So $\forall y\,\forall x \,x\in\emptyset\rightarrow x\in y$, because '$x\in\emptyset$' is always false, and anything follows from false.  This proves that $\forall y\, \emptyset\subseteq y$.

For the binary relation $\in$, there is an axiom called the axiom of regularity that states that for any non-empty set $S$, there is an $x\in S$ such that for all $y\in S$, $y\not\in x$.  This means that $x$ is an $\in$-minimal member of $S$.  This prevents things like having a set $u=\{u\}$ for which you get an infinite descending chain $\ldots u\in u\in u$.  This axiom prohibits inifinite descending $\in$-chains, so all descending $\in$-chains must end after finitely many steps in $\emptyset$.